# Python namespace packages with like-named subpackages

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

Here's the scenario:  I have one top-level package that contains a lot of code in one of its subpackages.  This guy looks something like this:

```
packagename
  __init__.py
  clients
    http_client.py
    otherclient.py
    __init__.py
  otherpackage
  etc
```

I need to turn `clients` into a namespace package, such that I can distribute a separate repo that has additional functionality for other clients (they have different dependencies and therefore need to be packaged separately for our builds to work)

The problem is that I'm extending subpackage and not the top level one.  For example, the dependent, new package looks like this:

```
packagename
  __init__.py
  clients
    __init__.py
    pipeline_client.py
```

No combination of the magic `pkgutil.extend_path` seems to be working.  I have tried all possible combinations of the following line in the various `__init__.py` files.

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Is there a way to make sure that the **subpath** is what gets extended?  Is such a thing possible (like-naming in a dependent namespace package)?  Should I just rename my subpackage in the dependent one?

**EDIT**

I should also note that within the parent package, there are some values inside `__init__.py` that are imported by child packages as used throughout.  This seems to be a problem with the names space module package.

Comment: Can't you create a file `packagename/data.py`  where you put what you currently have in `packagename/__init__.py`, then remove the `__init__.py`?

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm creating a dependent extension on a library that's already been developed by others:  would this be the best route to take then?  I'd like to modify their working code as little as possible.